# reset array of objects with lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

How can i reset the properties of objects in array that are diferent from 'db'?
I need to set others than 'db' to empty string.

```
var arr =   [
  {
    "db": "RHID",
    "prv_value": "1",
    "nxt_value": "1",
    "diagnostic": "1"
  },
  {
    "db": "CD_DOC_ID",
    "prv_value": "2",
    "nxt_value": "2",
    "diagnostic": "2"
  },
  ...
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I would do:

```
_.map(arr, function(i) {
  return _.assign(
    _(i).omit('db').mapValues(_.constant('')).value(),
    _.pick(i, 'db')
  );
});
```

Essentially, this uses [map()](https://lodash.com/docs#map) to create an array of new objects. It's using [assign()](https://lodash.com/docs#assign) to build the mapped object (it's basically concatenating two objects). The first argument passed to `assign()` is the object with the `db` property removed. This is done using [omit()](https://lodash.com/docs#omit). With this property removed, we can use [mapValues()](https://lodash.com/docs#mapValues) to set everything back to an empty string.

Now all we have to do is add the `db` property back, and this is why we're using `assign()`. The [pick()](https://lodash.com/docs#pick) function is used to get the `db` value.

Comment: thanks. As i am kind a newbie i use Michael L. cause not used to functional programming. Congratulations for your ebooks and your work.

Comment: I think you don't need the `omit()` method, and you can pretty much simplify this by chaining it all the way though `assign()`. **[See this](https://jsfiddle.net/ryeballar/rsp6rjbh/)**

Answer (score 2):

Use the [map](https://lodash.com/docs#map) function, it takes an array and a transformation function. It passes each element into the function for modification.

```
_.map(arr, function(curr) {
    for (var prop in curr) {
        // Please read http://phrogz.net/death-to-hasownproperty
        if (curr.hasOwnProperty(prop) && prop != 'db') {
            curr[prop] = '';
        }
    } 

    return curr;
});
```